# Make text appear for 5 seconds in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So at the start of my scene in my Unity game I want text to appear for a few seconds. How would I do this?

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/907707/need-text-to-display-after-5-seconds.html but just do in reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/907707/need-text-to-display-after-5-seconds.html

```
#pragma strict

public var myText : GameObject; // Assign the text to this in the inspector

function Start() {
yield WaitForSeconds (5);
myText.SetActive( true ); // Enable the text so it shows
yield WaitForSeconds (5);
myText.SetActive( false ); // Disable the text so it is hidden
}
```

Thanks for the answer, works great for me!

Comment: Linking to an external site is generally not considered a good answer here, as the external link isn't guaranteed to be there forever. Can you edit your answer to explain what the solution is?

Answer (score 0):

**you can Invoke a method after a certain amount of time like this. Place the script on the canvas and drag the text to the canvasText slot.**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class CanvasScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
 public Text canvasText1;
   void Start () 
   {
      Invoke("DisableText", 5f);//invoke after 5 seconds
   }
   void DisableText()
   { 
      canvasText1.enabled = false; 
   }    
}
```